CMake 3.29 enable_language(CUDA) doesn't set 'CUDA_FOUND' variable
I encountered an issue with enabling CUDA using the following CMake configuration, where it did not work as expected:
Code that did not work:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)

project(demo)

enable_language(CUDA)

if (CUDA_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "CUDA is enabled.")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CUDA is not found or enabled.")
endif ()


When running this configuration, the message shows "CUDA is not found or enabled."
Code that did work:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

project(demo)

if (POLICY CMP0146)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0146 OLD)
endif ()
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
if (CUDA_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "CUDA is enabled.")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CUDA is not found or enabled.")
endif ()


Command enable_language doesn't set *_FOUND variable. Actually, there is no reason to check success of enable_language call: would this call fail, CMake will print the error message and terminate immediately.

If you want to check presence of the language support, then you could use CheckLanguage module. In that case the variable to check is CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER:
# Import the module
include (CheckLanguage)
# Check whether CUDA is supported
check_language(CUDA)
if(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
  # CUDA language is supported. It is safe to enable it.
  enable_language(CUDA)
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CUDA is not found.")
endif()

